# htaccess file not working (for using AddType to parse HTML)

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2, add-type

I have downloaded a free HTML template and I'm willing to add a few php scripts in it's files. the apache2 server does not run php codes in the HTML file

there was no luck using .htaccess file 
here's how the .htaccess file looks:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .php
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm .shtml
```

what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me..

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .html .htm
```

Cheers